# Why is my express router not showing static content

Tags: express, static, router

I am serving my static files from index.js file which is in the root directory after which I connect my router.

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
 app.use('/users', usersRouter)
```

The router works fine. However, it does not serve any static content, which is located in the root directory under the folder named 'static'. If I access other pages which are in my main file index.js it serves those correctly with static content.

When I look at the console in the browser I get this following error.

The resource from “http://localhost:3000/users/css/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Why is this happening? And how do i fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your's path for the CSS file is incorrect

`http://localhost:3000/users/css/style.css`

it should be like `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css` or any other which you can define in `app.use()` function like:-

`app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: This is exactly the problem which I do not understand. I am using handlebars. My main layout has the following code. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >. For some reason when I go to the users path it adds this extra /users to the link.

Comment: your path is like this href="css/style.css it takes resources from the current path, which in your case is like / users of something. you can use it like href="/css/style.css" this so each time it takes resource path from the root of your domain

Comment: from example http://localhost:3000/ serves the static content correctly. The styles sheet link is <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">, but http://localhost:3000/users/register does not serve any static content even though the link for the style sheet is the same <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">. This is not a linking problem but a problem in the server I just do not understand where.

Comment: can you check the form source code if you can access the CSS file correctly for root and other pages, and their paths